# Устновка October CMS: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: .htaccess, cms, october

500 ошибка после установки October CMS, хостинг ТаймВэб. Как мне кажется следует изменить `htaccess`, но советы, которые находил, не помогли.

**Обновление**

Error_log

```
[error] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/k/*****/*****/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 50
```

Код

```
function app($make = null, $parameters = [])
{
    if (is_null($make)) return Container::getInstance();

    return Container::getInstance()->make($make, $parameters);
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите ошибки в `error_log` и, если сами не разберетесь, добавьте эту информацию в вопрос

Comment: Стоит PHP 5.4, без этого установка не прошла бы.

Comment: Покажите вывод файла с таким содержимым: `<?php echo phpversion();`

Comment: Огромное спасибо, действительно хостер в панели управления говорил одно, а на самом деле выдавал старую версию.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего старовата версия PHP. Литералы `[]` появились начиная с версии PHP 5.4. Обратитесь в техподдержку timeweb узнайте версию PHP и попросите обновить или смените хостера.

Кстати [тут](https://octobercms.com/docs/setup/installation#system-requirements) прямо говорится, что нужен PHP >= 5.4. Это из разряда "так не бывает". В приведенной вами строке только в одном месте квадратные скобки и к ним не вижу поводов для претензий. А вот в синтетическом тесте, который я провел на версии 5.3 выдается как раз такая же ошибка.

---

Ответ из комментариев участника [@tutankhamun](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/177613/).